# how to use cell.getArabicOption(int arabicoption)

Tags: java, android, itext

i don't know what the integer can i use it in this function 
so i have a problem to show arabic in my creating pdf
i use iText library to get this function
if some on know how to use it please inform me

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `int` values such as 0, 1, 2,... in your code as it will be very hard for people to know what these values mean (just like you currently have no idea which options are available).

Instead you should use constants that are provided by iText. The API documentation informs you that the parameters for the `setArabicOptions()` method can be a combination of:

- `ColumnText.AR_NOVOWEL`: Eliminate the arabic vowels,
- `ColumnText.AR_COMPOSEDTASHKEEL`: Compose the tashkeel in the ligatures, or
- `ColumnText.AR_LIG`: Do some extra double ligatures.

If you want to know which exact `int` values correspond with these constants, you can always print them out or look inside the code, but there is no reason to do this.

The different values are actually to be used as flags (or bits). You can combine these values like this:

```
column.setArabicOptions(
    ColumnText.AR_NOVOWEL |
    ColumnText.AR_COMPOSEDTASHKEEL |
    ColumnText.AR_LIG);
```